# updating one sheet based on another which has been auto created

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a workbook that has sheets added to each day with data on with set values which need to be entered onto a front sheet for kpi reporting

the tabs that are being added each day (via a macro) all have the date(dd-mm-yy)as a name and the data that needs to be copied is always in the same cell (C62) and need to be copied onto the front sheet in the column for that day

I've tried using the indirect but keep getting error's and have also looked at vlookup and index/match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly the indirect function should work:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(A1,"dd-mm-yy")&"'!C62")
```

Where A1 contains the date of the tab you are getting the total for (as a number).  The indirect formula here puts it in the number format (dd-mm-yy) of your tabs.